# How can I forward request using HandlerFilterFunction?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

A server environment requires an endpoint for `/some/health`.

I already configured actuator.

Rather changing the actuator's function, I'm thinking forwarding `/some/health` to the `/actuator/health`.

And I'm trying to do with `HandlerFilterFunction`.

```java
@Configuration
public class SomeHealthFilterFunction
        implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {

    private static final String PATTERN = "/some/health";

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(ServerRequest request,
                                       HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> next) {
        if (PATTERN.equals(request.requestPath().pathWithinApplication().value())) {
            RequestPath requestPath
                    = request.requestPath().modifyContextPath("/actuator/health");
            // How can I call next.handle, here?
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the origin request and do `next.handle(...)`?

Comment: do you specifically need to use a `HandlerFilterFunction`? I have a solution using a `WebFilter` but no sure if that is applicable for you

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen Nope. I'm not sure of `HandlerFilterFunction`. That's just one of my googling results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example `WebFilter` that will reroute all calls from `/some/health` to `/actuator/health`

```
@Component
public class RerouteWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        if ("/some/health".equals(request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value())) {
            ServerHttpRequest mutatedServerRequest = request.mutate().path("/actuator/health").build();
            serverWebExchange = serverWebExchange.mutate().request(mutatedServerRequest).build();
        }

        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```